# Windows Phone 8 WebBrowser presents it's content in scroll view

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I have added a WebBrowser control on a page. I have added a single paragraph(some text) in the html file which is loaded in the WebBrowser. I get the content height of the html by adding javascript to the html file and get notified in the app, so that im able to set the exact content height to the WebBrowser, so that my WebBrowser's height is set to fit it's content but the WebBrowser presents it's content in a scroll view. Does WebBrowser always present it's content on scroll view, is that the default behavior ? if yes can we change this behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

**this is default behavior of windows phone web browser control. There is no API to restrict this behavior.**